# function being zero at one point implies it is zero everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

The following basic analysis problem came up in one of my applications: Let $f$ and $h$ be two smooth (at least $C^1$) functions $f,h\colon I \to\mathbb{R}$ with $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ an interval. I know that $h>0$ and that $f^\prime = h\cdot f$.

I think that now $$\exists x_0\in I\quad f(x_0) = 0\ \Rightarrow\ \forall x\in I\quad f(x)=0.$$

Is this true or am I missing something here? Is there a basic proof for that? I thought about interpreting $f^\prime = hf$ as an ODE and proving it this way, but that seems a bit over the top for such a simple problem.

Comment: What did you get when you solved the ODE?

Comment: Using an initial value at $x_0$ the solution to this ODE is $f(x)=f(x_0)\cdot\mathrm{exp}(\int_{x_0}^xh(t)dt)$, which implies the statement. But is there a way to see this without having to resort to ODEs?

Comment: I think your question definitely has to do with ODEs. Have you heard of the Gronwall lemma ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality

Comment: Thanks. Not heard of the Grönwall lemma, yet. I'll take a look.